# Need perl routine to return true or false as to whether XML file has an associated DTD or schema

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

Is it possible to create a function something like "got_dtd(file.xml)" or "got_schema(file.xml)", where you just feed it the name of an xml file and it will return a true/false as to whether there is an associated dtd/schema for the XML file? I searched high and low for days and can not figure out how to do this. I've even searched through Perl cpan modules designed to parse XML, I can't figure out how to write a script that just returns an indicator that the XML has an internal or external DTD or schema associated with it.Can someone point me in the direction of where begin with this?

Comment: a good practice on StackOverflow is to provide you effort and investigation first. Please, consider editing your question.

Comment: Your validator should check for you

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use XMl::Twig. Details can be found here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1106259.